# How do I resolve <libavformat/avformat.h> not being found by Xcode?

Tags: xcode, macos

I just tried to compile an older version of code and the compiler says that avformat.h cannot be found.  I did a quick Google search but couldn't find out the reason for this problem.  Is the library deprecated or am I missing something?

Comment: Do you have the library that contains this header? Have you installed it?

Comment: I installed ffmpeg-devel and am finding the header files, and will be adding that to the source path in Xcode...